# Need help parallelizing the C++ code using openmp

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, nested, openmp

I have generated all of the 32 bit permutations of 16 0's and 16 1's line by line in a text file, values.txt.
Eg-

```
00000000000000001111111111111111
00000000000000010111111111111111
00000000000000011011111111111111
00000000000000011101111111111111
```

and so on....

Let us consider that each of the line of the text file is a boolean function.
I need to check for the reversibility of this function in a domain.

For this I picked up the first line from the text file and stored it into a column matrix of dimension 32x1, matrix a[][].

inside the nested for loops I am basically generating the domain values in form of a 3x3 matrix for which I need to check for the reversibility of the function.
I created a matrix g[][] of dimension 3x3 that is going to store the binary representation of all no. from 1 to 2^9. eg-
for 0 matrix g would look like-

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

for 1, matrix g would be-

```
0 0 0 
0 0 0
0 0 1
```

for 2 matrix g would be

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 1 0
```

and so on upto 2^9.

for each matrix generated above from 0 to 2^9, I am computing a new matrix u[][] of dimension 3x3 based on my function.
This is done by reading 5 adjacent values to each element of the matrix.

for eg- consider g matrix to be

```
0 0 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
```

I pickup the first element,i.e,g[0][0], compute a new value for it using the five adjacent values(top value,left value,element itself,right value,below value) namely g[2][0],g[0][2],g[0][0],g[0][1],g[1][0]. These 5 no. combinely represent a binary no. I calculate its decimal equivalent and the decimal value corresponds to the row no. of matrix a[][] with which I have to update the vale of u[0][0]. 
I will repeat the above process for every element of g and will finally have a u matrix of 3x3.

this complete process was for one matrix, that it matrix corresponding to 0.
Like this for every g[][] matrix from 0 to 2^9, I will create 2^9 matrices.

At any point of time if for two matrices g[][], matrix u[][] happens to be same I abort the function, reading the second line of text file and again begin the above process, i.e., I am not interested with functions that result in duplicate matrices. If all of the 2^9 matrices happen to be different, I write the value of the corresponding function(line from text file) into another text file.

So therefore,summing up, I need to create a total of 60 crore* 2^9 matrices for the overall computation.

The thing is that for a particular function from the text files,the 2^9 matrices are calculated individually. If somehow I could parallelize them, I would lessen the computation time greatly...

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
using namespace boost::multiprecision;
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <cctype>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <set>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define convertToString(x) #x
using namespace boost::assign;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("values.txt");
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("haha.txt");
    short a[32][1];
    while(!infile.eof())
    {
        string STRING;
        getline(infile,STRING);
        set<string> SET;
        int count=0;


        for(int i=0;i<32;i++)
        {
                a[i][0]=STRING.at(i)-'0';
        }


        int g[9];
        int u[9];
        char buffer[10];
        buffer[9] = 0;
        uint16_t f = 0;

        int max = (int)pow(2,3);


        for(int r=0;r<max && count!=1;r++)
        {
           for(int s=0;s<max && count!=1;s++)
           {
              for(int t=0;t<max && count!=1;t++)
              {
                for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
                {
                   g[i] = (f & (1 << (8 - i))) != 0;
                }
                ++f;

                u[0]=a[(g[6]*2*2*2*2)+(g[2]*2*2*2)+(g[0]*2*2)+(g[1]*2)+(g[3]*1)][0];
                u[1]=a[(g[7]*2*2*2*2)+(g[0]*2*2*2)+(g[1]*2*2)+(g[2]*2)+(g[4]*1)][0];
                u[2]=a[(g[8]*2*2*2*2)+(g[1]*2*2*2)+(g[2]*2*2)+(g[0]*2)+(g[5]*1)][0];
                u[3]=a[(g[0]*2*2*2*2)+(g[5]*2*2*2)+(g[3]*2*2)+(g[4]*2)+(g[6]*1)][0];
                u[4]=a[(g[1]*2*2*2*2)+(g[3]*2*2*2)+(g[4]*2*2)+(g[5]*2)+(g[7]*1)][0];
                u[5]=a[(g[2]*2*2*2*2)+(g[4]*2*2*2)+(g[5]*2*2)+(g[3]*2)+(g[8]*1)][0];
                u[6]=a[(g[3]*2*2*2*2)+(g[8]*2*2*2)+(g[6]*2*2)+(g[7]*2)+(g[0]*1)][0];
                u[7]=a[(g[4]*2*2*2*2)+(g[6]*2*2*2)+(g[7]*2*2)+(g[8]*2)+(g[1]*1)][0];
                u[8]=a[(g[5]*2*2*2*2)+(g[7]*2*2*2)+(g[8]*2*2)+(g[6]*2)+(g[2]*1)][0];


                for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
                {
                   buffer[i] = '0' + u[i];
                }
                if(!SET.insert(::std::string(buffer)).second)
                {
                   count = 1;
                }
             }
          }
        }

        if(count==0)
        {
            outfile<<STRING<<"\n";
            cout<<STRING<<"\n";
        }


    }
        infile.close();
        outfile.close();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Correct indentation would help getting through the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for using a two-dimenstional array, when the second dimension is only 1. Simply define a[32] and leave out the second index operator ([0]) anywhere you are accessing the array (probably only improves readability, I would expect that the compiler optimizes it to this anyway - but you're on the safe side then).

Your convert function is ineffecive, prepending all the time to a string will create a new string object each time. Do this once in a buffer like this:

```
char buffer[10];
buffer[9] = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
{
    buffer[i] = '0' + ((dec & (1 << (8 - i))) != 0);
}
return ::std::string(buffer);
```

Is there any reason for only outputting nine digits and not all 16?

Same for your u array within the loop...

One level higher:

```
string binary=in.convert(f++);

for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    g[i]=binary.at(i)-'0';
```

You first converted a string, then you convert it back to numbers? Why not pass in the array to your convert function and assign the values directly (0 and 1, not '0' and '1')?

You are using the convert function only at a single place - maybe you want to have it inline. At least, make it static, as it does not rely on any class members (and if no other member functions remain, rather have a namespace instead of a class).

---

**Edit:** I allowed to simply inline the whole stuff (left out pragmas):

```
int g[9];
int u[9];
char buffer[10];
buffer[9] = 0;
uint16_t f = 0;

int max = (int)pow(2,3);
for(int r=0;r<max;r++
{
    for(int s=0;s<max;s++)
    {
        for(int t=0;t<max;t++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
            {
                g[i] = (f & (1 << (8 - i))) != 0;
            }
            ++f;
            /* calculate the u array here */
            for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
            {
                buffer[i] = '0' + (u[i] != 0);
            }
            if(!SET.insert(::std::string(buffer)).second)
            {
                count = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Precalculated the power, not sure if the compiler would have optimized it away...

You might get some additional performance gain if you use for your u and g arrays the integer types of which the size matches the CPU register size...

You are not checking, which values your array `a` can get. Possibly, any one could be. If you guarantee that these values are always only 0 or 1, you could even shorten the code minimally more:

```
buffer[i] = '0' + u[i];
```

---

Leave your loops early:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    for(int r=0;r<(int)pow(2,3);r++)
    {
        for(int s=0;s<(int)pow(2,3);s++)
        {
            #pragma omp parallel for shared(SET,count,f)
            for(int t=0;t<(int)pow(2,3);t++)
            {
                /* ... */
                    count = 1;
                    goto EndOfLoop;
                /* ... */
            }
        }
    }
    :EndOfLoop;
}
```

["It is illegal to branch (goto) into or out of a parallel region"](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/), but not within, as I read this... Variant would be to have

```
for(int r=0; count == 0 && r<(int)pow(2,3);r++)
```

for all three loops, but these additional if's cost performance...

Comment: Great Suggestions!! Actually I donot have very good knowledge of C++ and moreover its for a project that I have to implement on an HPC. One more thing, could you suggest some edits in the openMP lines, because they are really eating my head, I am not getting the required output. :(

Comment: But that's a different question then - So what exactly *is* the required output? (Sorry for late reply, have been out with my kids...).

Comment: Added an explanation to my question. Hope it would you give you an insight about the output. I am not a good programmer in C++, I considered your suggestion of using buffer but was not getting the same output because I need a 9 bit binary representaion and it was returning just 2 bit.
If you could please implement the dec2bin function, I will be grateful.

Comment: @ShubhamJain A sorry, there was a bug in (wanted to be especially clever, missed the indices, though). Should work in theory now, can't test it until tonight, however.

Comment: Nope not working still, but no problem. I will be waiting and trying myself too. Thanks for your time!!

Comment: @ShubhamJain This happens if editing too quickly by heart - you forget some parentheses...

Comment: @ShubhamJain Ok, inlined the whole stuff - I think, Dec2Bin is just a helper class and not of any further use than here - so I propose to drop it...

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!! You optimised the code very well. Only a last thing, is this program thread safe? and if not, what is not thread safe in this?

Comment: how can I modify the decimal to binary conversion part in order to get a 128 bit output instead of 9 bit output? I tried: for(int i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
                                                                       {
                                                                       g[i] = (f & (1 << (127 - i))) != 0;
                                                                       }                              but i am not getting the exact ouput, the bits seem to repeat.

Comment: Critical for threadsafety are the two arrays u and g, as both threads write to it simultaneouly. Best is each thread having its own copy (a is not critical, as only read access). I'm not very adept to OMP, so I'd leave it to you to figure this out (possibly it is sufficient to declare the arrays within the inner-most for loop?).

Comment: To assign 128 bits this way you need an integer with 128 bits. f as uint16_t has only 16 bits, though, and as far as I remember, shifting more bits than the underlying type has is UB... If you actually need 128 bits, I would do the following (as there is no native type): use two `uint64_t f_high = 0, f_low = 0;` Incrementing then as `++f_low; f_high += f_low == 0;` (increment high part each time low part overflows). Then to the loop with 64 for f_low and f_high each, with `g[i + 64]` for the high part.

Comment: @ShubhamJain Addition to my latest comments: For threadsafety, you have to protect this kind of increment, as it is not atomic (actually, using the ++ operator is not either - possibly, however, OMP can cope with?).

Comment: okh thanks a lot. Any suggestions where can I get the best help implementing the openmp part??